# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. on iOS8 Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Hi [this page](http://www.nzud.co.nz/#/products) on my site works fine on desktop browser, but has a weird bug on iOS8 Safari:

The index template doesn't show up, and there's a error in the console:

TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.

and it points to the following line:

```
}), e("rsvp/promise/all", ["../utils", "exports"], function(e, t) {
    "use strict";
    var r = e.isArray, n = e.isNonThenable;
    t["default"] = function(e, t) {
        var i = this;
        return new i(function(t, a) {
            function o(e) {
                return function(r) {
                    c[e] = r, 0===--u && t(c)
                }
            }
            function s(e) {
                u = 0, a(e)
            }
            if (!r(e))
                throw new TypeError("You must pass an array to all.");
            var l, u = e.length, c = new Array(u);
            if (0 === u) // This is the line with error
                return void t(c);
            for (var h = 0; h < e.length; h++)
                l = e[h], n(l) ? (c[h] = l, 0===--u && t(c)) : i.cast(l).then(o(h), s)
        }, t)
    }
}), e("rsvp/promise/cast", ["exports"], function(e) {
    "use strict";
```

Is it a known bug to mobile safari, is there fix of it?

Answer (score 8):

Maintainer of RSVP here, sorry that you ran into this issue.

Firstly, it appears you are using an older version of RSVP. I would recommend upgrading.

Unfortunately it appears this issue may be related to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5629 which *appears* to just be that JSC for non-64bit devices running iOS 8 is just broken when in 'use strict' mode. In my observations it only happens in specific situations and then only when the code in question has become optimized.

Again I am unsure if upgrading will help you, but you should consider it regardless. Additionally, if the problem persists removing all `use strict` statements may be the best option.

If no solution appears soon, I will likely publish an update to RSVP with the use strict statements removed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to remove all the  `"use strict";`'s from your code? From my understanding it only seems to occur with 3. generation iPads.