# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property. ring.js: Line 333

Tags: javascript, safari, ring.js

I have two Mac systems with different Safari versions. I'm facing this problem in Safari version **9.0.1**, while it works fine in version **8.0**.

[THIS](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7306139) support blog mentions a similar issue. While I don't find this error in other browsers like Chrome or Firefox in both the Macs, but the Safari versions seems to create problem.

I came across a unaccepted solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174594/typeerror-attempted-to-assign-to-readonly-property-on-ios8-safari), that suggests to remove `"use strict"` and that solves my problem (I have removed it from Line 28 of **ring.js**). But, I'm not sure about what side effects this may have. While I read the advantages of **Why Strict Mode?** [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp), I wonder why a modern browser(Safari 9.0.1) doesn't support it.

Can anyone throw some light to this?

Comment: @JaromandaX I use **giggle** for audio/video calls, **ring.js** comes as one of the source JS files